# Help with a color map

Tags: plotting, import, color, data

In this document http://pastebin.com/XEyrDHyB the first 2 coloums are the position and the third the value of the fuction.

I need to create a 2d image where in each position the value of the function is represented by a color. The highest value would have a different colour from the lowest. It would be great if  the areas where the values of the function are similar are marked.

Comment: See [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a few ways to visualize the data:

I've imported your data as a 524 by 3 matrix:

```
Dimensions[data]
```

> ```
> {524, 3}
> ```

The easiest way is with `ListDensityPlot`:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

For the other methods, I rescale the function values to run from 0 to 1:

```
data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[data[[All, 3]]];
```

A different approach is to use `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[
 {Hue[#3], {Hue[#3], Cuboid[{#1, #2} - 0.015, {#1, #2} + 0.015]}} & @@@ data, 
 Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

Another is with `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[
 Style[{#1, #2}, Hue[#3]] & @@@ data,
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

---

As for marking similar values, you can use `ClusterClassify`. Here I partition into 4 groups:

```
c = ClusterClassify[data, 4];

Do[color[j] = RandomColor[], {j, 1, 4}]

Graphics[{color[#3], Cuboid[{#1, #2} - 0.015, {#1, #2} + 0.015]} & @@@ 
  Map[Append[Most[#], c[#]] &, data], Frame -> True]
```

[image]